# eBPF BPF_ARRAY lookup

Tags: c, ebpf

I am trying to build a packet counter with eBPF and XDP. I need a way to keep track of the total number of packets received. Since I'm using XDP I use a BPF_ARRAY and increment it every time a packet is received. The problem is I can't seem to access the stored value using the provided lookup() function.

Here is how I create the BPF_ARRAY.

```
BPF_ARRAY(counter, u64, 1);
```

Here is how I try to access and use the stored value. The type of output.avg is u64.

```
int cindex = 0;
counter.increment(&cindex);
long current_count = counter.lookup(&cindex);
output.avg = current_count;
```

BPF gives me this warning and fails to compile.

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'long' with
      an expression of type 'u64 *' (aka 'unsigned long long *') [-Wint-conversion]
                        long current_count = counter.lookup(&cindex);
```

Comment: I don't know about the library, but won't `u64 current_count = *counter.lookup(&cindex);` work?

Comment: The warning tells you what the issue is: `counter.lookup()` returns a pointer, not an integer. Try declaring `current_count` as a pointer instead of just a `long`?

Comment: @veryconfusedrobot - There's no diagnostic for `counter.increment(&cindex)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix my errors. I'm new to C so the pointers confused me a little bit.

```
int cindex = 0;
counter.increment(cindex);
unsigned long long *current_count = counter.lookup(&cindex);

if(current_count != NULL){          
    output.avg = *current_count;    
}
```